# Is there any difference with the X11 atoms XA_WM_NAME and "_NET_WM_NAME"?

Tags: c, x11, windowing

Is there any difference with the atom defined in `XA_WM_NAME` defined in `Xatom.h` and the one  got using `XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_NAME", False)`?

Edit: I made a little program which prints the integer value of both and I got: `_NET_WM_NAME: 312, XA_WM_NAME: 39`, so, they represent different atoms. What are the differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are different atoms, but they both represent the title of the window.

[`_NET_WM_NAME`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#id2522738) is part of the newer [XDG/freedesktop.org window manager spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/).
Like other XDG string properties, it's defined as a UTF-8 encoded string, whereas the "legacy" `WM_NAME` uses the X "compound text" encoding.

Window managers that respect the XDG spec will use the `_NET_WM_NAME` property instead of `WM_NAME` if both are set.