# Naming a new window in x11

Tags: c, linux, window, x11, xorg

I found out a terminal command to rename a window in x11. But I am looking for a xlib function (a C code snippet) for naming a newly created window. I looked into the window attributes, but there is no option for that.

For creating new window: 
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#C

For window attributes:
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/

For command-line renaming:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286723/how-does-one-change-the-title-of-any-window-in-x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706589/is-there-any-difference-with-the-x11-atoms-xa-wm-name-and-net-wm-name - presumably you'd set the _NET_WM_NAME (and WM_NAME that gets ignored)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273292/how-to-change-net-wm-name-x-library

Answer (score 3):

Regardez la fonction XStoreName();